# Capture multimedia keys from a web site?

Tags: web, key, multimedia

Is there a way to capture multimedia keys from a web site?

Comment: Just curious - did the answer below work for you? The question doesn't seem all that specific...

Answer (score 1):

try this jquery plugin(it supports all the keys)

http://jshotkeys.googlepages.com/test-static-01.html

if they can be find than you are in luck, however i think it wont work.